# Excerpt with thumbnail that links to post

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, post

I'm quite new to wordpress and PHP, having just switched over from blogger. I hoping someone could help me here, because I have been looking around the web without really finding the solution I'm looking for,

I was wondering if there is a way to make the excerpt show the first image in the post and then have the image link to the actual post? I've tried variations with featured image, but either I get two images in excerpt or no image in the post...

I would love it if someone knew a code that did it all :)

Here's my index file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Displays the index section of the theme.
 *
 * @package Theme Horse
 * @subpackage Clean_Retina
 * @since Clean Retina 1.0
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    /** 
     * cleanretina_before_main_container hook
     */
    do_action( 'cleanretina_before_main_container' );
?>

<div id="container">
    <?php
        /** 
         * cleanretina_main_container hook
         *
         * HOOKED_FUNCTION_NAME PRIORITY
         *
         * cleanretina_content 10
         */
        do_action( 'cleanretina_main_container' );
    ?>

</div><!-- #container -->




<?php
    /** 
     * cleanretina_after_main_container hook
     */
    do_action( 'cleanretina_after_main_container' );
?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>

   <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <p><?php echo get_new_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you already have,  and the code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want the first image in your post to get inside your excerpt. So I have a better solution, why not make another function inside functions.php file that contains your image concatenated with the original excerpt?

Add to your functions.php

```
function get_new_excerpt(){
    $str = '';
    $img = '<img src="'.catch_that_image().'">';
    $linkedImage = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.$img.'</a>';
    $str .= '<div class="post-image">'.$linkedImage.'</div>';
    $str .= '<div class="post-excerpt">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>';
    return $str;
}
// Catch first Image from http://css-tricks.com/
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches[1][0];

  if(empty($first_img)) {
    $first_img = "/path/to/default.png";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

then in your index.php or what ever page you want to show this function, insert:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <div class="post">
            <h1 class="post-header"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="post-info">
                <?php echo get_new_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
       </div>
<?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

you might want to add some css style like:

```
    <style>
    .post {
        clear: both;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .post h1.post-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .post .post-info {
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .post .post-image {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
    }
    .post .post-image img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .post .post-excerpt {
        float: right;
        width: calc(100% - 120px);
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

I hope I have understood you. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that works to get the first image in the excerpt. However, I also want that image in the excerpt to link to the full post. Is that possible?

Comment: @moiety yes, sorry i forgot that, I have updated it now.

Comment: No, sorry, that doesn't work. All I got is the excerpt, no image and then on the bottom of the main page I got the image link that links to the post. I'm using clean retina as a template, but I'm trying to alter it.Right now I have no plugins activated and no other code.... If that information is any help...

Comment: @moiety I just Fixed a little syntax issue, now I tested it and it works. my wordpress version is 3.8.1

Comment: I know I must be doing something wrong. I put the code in the index.php, but still, all I get are the full posts lower on the page below the excerpts. Is there any specific place in the index.php file i should place this? I also have wordpress 3.8.1.

Comment: @moiety can you share us your index.php code, may be that will help me to help you.

Comment: Added it above. Thank you so much for taking the time to help :)

Comment: @moiety thats because you have inserted my code under `<?php get_footer(); ?>` . I have updated my code, but remember that you must insert it above the `<?php get_footer(); ?>`.

Comment: I'm sorry to say it still didn't work... I also didn't place the code below the footer in the actual index.php, I just did it. Sorry for confusing you... I'm pretty close to giving up right now...

Comment: try to remove everything from index.php, keep only `get_header()`, and my code. and `get_footer()`. and see if this works, then start adding line by line from original index.php until you debug the real issue.